# using "define" in C language both as int and as char

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to use a #define such us the following, as int and as char

```
#define name joe
```

This way it's int, but I want to be able to printf this #define and get the word Joe.
I know I can use

```
#define name "Joe"
```

But then I will gave up its "int abilities".

what can I do?
thx guys!

Comment: What do you mean "int abilities"?
You first example does not produce and integer value, it just makes a label.

Comment: int abillites like using it in a comparsion with an enum: "enum nameEnum joe == name"

Comment: Is this what you are asking? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html#Stringizing

Answer (score 3):

The `#` preprocessor operator turns a macro parameter into a string literal. The output of:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define name            Joe
#define Helper(x)       #x
#define Stringify(x)    Helper(x)

int main(void)
{
    int name = 4;
    printf("%s is %d.\n", Stringify(name), name);
}
```

is:

> Joe is 4.

Two macros are necessary because the expansion of `x` in for `Stringify` would not be performed until after the `#` is applied. So we need `Stringify` to expand `x` and then `Helper` to produce the string literal.

Do not use this in production code without good reason. Playing games with the preprocessor should be used carefully.

Comment: Beat me to the punch.  I'll delete my answer.